# Setting the transparency of a WPF ImageSource (equivalent to GDI Matrix33 = 0.5f)?

Tags: c#, wpf

Does WPF have an equivalent to this?

```
ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes();
ia.SetColorMatrix(new ColorMatrix { Matrix33 = 0.5f }, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
```

In other words, can I adjust the transparency of a WPF ImageSource (or any other drawing related class e.g. BitmapImage), or is GDI the best choice here?

I don't intend to draw the image onto a window, so I think that rules out using the Image class(?)

(My line of thought with trying to use WPF instead of GDI is primarily because I'm under the impression that with WPF I can have hardware acceleration, but from what I've seen so far, it seems that it's only applying to a very limited subset of image manipulation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your comments I created a sample project which can modify the alpha channel quickly using WriteableBitmapEx as a basis and uploaded to my [Company Blog](http://www.abtsoftware.co.uk/News/tabid/93/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/5/Updating_the_Alpha_Channel_of_a_WPF_BitmapSource.aspx). You'll have to forgive the formatting, its a new website and still has some glitches to be ironed out! The download link is on the page titled BitmapAlphaChannel

You're correct in saying WPF's hardware acceleration is only applied to a limited subset of features. For instance, all layout is done on the CPU, tessellation on the CPU, only the final rendering is done on the GPU. The result is WPF in my experience is slower than GDI+, certainly GDI. However it can be pushed in the right direction to do what you want, in the speed you want it to!

Comment: Sorry, that site no longer exists. I would suggest looking at the http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ samples instead.

Answer (score 2):

check out [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/), which provides a set of extension methods for manipulating bitmaps in memory with WPF and Silverlight.

There is nothing in WPF per-se that will allow you to do want, but the WPF/Silverlight class [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) provides a fast, low-level API to drawing/manipulating and is native to WPF.

[WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) then builds on this by providing extension methods to do GDI-like operations. There is a [Convolute](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/82092#1765130) function which allows convolving an image with a matrix, so you could do the above. Note WB-Ex is a silverlight library but they also provide an unmaintained WPF version which although incomplete, can be extended to keep up to date with the Silverlight version.

Other than that I'd suggest rolling your own. If all you wish to do is modify the opacity to 0.5f then rather than convolve I'd suggest writing a specific function to do that based on the above examples

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to port a method to WPF over from those convolute methods, so I gave the `ForEach` method a go from [here](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/82092#1765208), and found it a lot slower than using GDI - and that method's using unsafe code too! I'm trying to see whether I can use WPF for such operations since it's got hardware acceleration, but now it seems that only really applies to things like Visuals... if there's no better alternatives I guess I'll just have to use GDI.

Comment: I dunno, i've had WriteableBitmapEx do some pretty fast operations. What exactly were you trying? Be advised quite a lot of the extensions have a Bitmap.Lock() before and after, which is a slow operation. 

Taking the code in that library as a starting point, have you considered iterating over the pixels (from unsafe pointer) in steps of 4 and modifying the result? The reason being an image in the format BGRA will have every fourth byte equal to an alpha channel byte. This could be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

An image has an `opacity` field, which is a value between 1.0 (completely opaque) to 0.0 (invisible)

For example:

```
<Image 
 Height="107" 
 Margin="367,0,473,83" 
 Source="Images/4.png" 
 Stretch="Fill" 
   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="0.5"/>
```

Comment: But isn't the only way to get that image back into something I can, for example, save, is through something like a RenderTargetBitmap? Wouldn't that involve a loss of opacity?